# Selecting Multiple Tables On Same Page

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, this

I have several tables on the same page. I am attempting to write jQuery code that would individually count the rows to each of my tables on the page, and depending whether the # of rows are even or odd, apply different CSS to each individual table.

Using jQuery's .each function, I am able to select each table. But I need a way to count the number of rows in that individual table using the "this" keyword. If there was just one table I could use

```
var amountOfRows = $(".data  tbody  tr").length;
```

But since there are multiple tables I need some code that incorporates the "this" keyword to individually get each row length.

So I am really just wanting to know how to use the "this" keyword to be able to read the # of rows of each of my tables on my page.

Here is a basic jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49jNn/1/

Here is a simplified version of my HTML code, I have 2-4 a page.

```
<table class="data">
    <thead>
        //head row
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        //footer row
    </tfoot>

    //I want the number of these rows
    <tr>
        //multiple <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        //multiple <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        //multiple <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery code so far, able to loop through the # of tables on a page.

```
$('table').each(function() {
    alert("table");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(selector, context)`;

```
$('tbody tr', this).length;
```

or `find` method:

```
$(this).find('tbody tr').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your each selector you might want to try something like this,

```
$('table').each(function(e, table) {
    console.log(['Table length', $(table).find('tbody tr').length]);
});​
```

Where e is going to be the index and table is the current table in the each statement.

$(table) will take the javascript object and reference it as a jQuery object which will allow you to use the .find('tbody tr') to get the rows in that table.